# Contourf with seaborn using numpy 2D heatmap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a 2D heatmap stored with a numpy array, which I use to produce a contourf plot with matplot lib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.contourf(heatmap, levels=10, cmap='coolwarm')
```

The result is here :

[image]

I'd basically want to do the same using seaborn and kdeplot, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking here. If you got the result you want, what's the use of seaborn? Also, how does this relate to a KDE ?

Comment: Thanks for your message, I try to avoid using core matplotlib as much as I can, I find the doc and syntax very confusing and it takes me hours to get things right with it.
About KDE, it was a guess, since seaborn seems to be using it for heatmaps.

Comment: Seaborn sits on top of matplotlib. Hence everything you can plot with seaborn can be done with matplotlib as well; but the reverse is not true. A seaborn KDE plot is a matplotlib contour plot of a KDE, where seaborn does the job of calculating the KDE from the input data. If you don't have distribution data, you would want to plot a contour plot directly with matplotlib.

Comment: Alright thx! I have the distribution of my data, computed using numpy.histogram2d